# How did this user undelete a post deleted by review?

Tags: support, review-queues, deleted-answers, vote-to-undelete

[This "answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23358711/851811) was posted yesterday. It is NAA as the OP herself acknowledges (*Not able to comment over there so, writing here.*).

The post was [deleted from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4682004) and then undeleted by the OP as shown in its [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23358711/revisions).

Can an author undelete posts that have been deleted by reviewers? Or did something go wrong somewhere there?

Comment: Unfortunately, unless a post was deleted by a moderator it can be undeleted by the OP.

Comment: Related: ["Answers deleted via Recommend Deletion votes in review should not be undeletable by the answerer"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226993/answers-deleted-via-recommend-deletion-votes-in-review-should-not-be-undeletable)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A user can still see their deleted posts in their profile. Thus, if they notice it was deleted they can undelete it. There are exceptions to this, like when a moderator deletes a post or when the post is deleted by trusted users. Then they do not have the option to undelete it by themselves.

Comment: Clarification: a user can only see recent posts that have been deleted.  They can't see just any deleted post.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Clarification to that: Unless they have a link or it is an answer and they visit the question, right?

Comment: @Deduplicator definitely, but this answer specific said that a user can see deleted posts in their profile, which is not quite true except if the post is recent (not deleted recently, but was posted recently then deleted).